# How to slice an Image Border for use in CSS?

Tags: html, css, border

i am trying to get an image border sliced for use in css.

### Here is the Box borders i want to use:

[image: Featured box Image Border]

### Here is part of the code for the Box:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="featured_box1">
                <div class="Content1">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Content for Featured Box</p>
                </div>
            </div>               
</div>
```

How should i slice the images, should i slive a small area and then repeat-y for each side. and then create 4 new divs to insert the corners of the border ?

So how to handle the corners of the borders ?

Which is the best way to get the box displayed with fasting loading speed?

Comment: Surely for this kind of border you better use css border:3px solid blue

Comment: @amadeus I'm not sure there's a CSS way of getting that middle-biased box shadow without images, though.

Comment: @Matt Gibson: Wow, very subtle, escaped me.

Comment: I need to use images, thats not an issue. the issue is the Corners. Do i have to use additional DIVs to place the top/bottom (left and right) corners ?

Comment: Which dimensions of the box are fixed? Width? Height? Neither? Both?

Comment: @thirtydot, The box width is fixed, both width and height. How do I use 4 corners with divs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @thirtydot, The box width is fixed,
>   both width and height. How do I use 4
>   corners with divs ? – Ibn Saeed

Maybe I'm missing something, but if the box is a fixed size, can't you just set the `width` and `height` of your `div` to the exact dimensions, and set it as a `background-image`?

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7DgNg/

Comment: Yes, i know that. But I want to slice the borders and the corners. I am trying not to use the complete image as a background, want to keep the size at a minimum. For e.g using only 1px height selection from the left and right borders and setting it = repeat-y

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If it's so that you can change the `width`/`height` of the box at a later date, that's fine, and I'll update my answer. However, if it's to "reduce the file size" by only using a tiny image, it's *not worth it*: your image is only `6.7KB`. So, what's your reasoning here?

Comment: @thirydot, you are correct about the size. Somehow, when i sliced the full border with the background, the PNG size was coming around 1.2 MB. I checked again now and its 3.4Kb. Quite good. I think the problem appeared during slicing as it also caught some heavy image.